# Find all asymptotes for function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I start by calculating the domain, which is $D = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\}$.

So now, to find vertical asymptotes, I consider the following limits:

$$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2+2k\pi)^{+}}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2+2k\pi)^{-}}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$$

which are equal to plus and minus infinity, respectively, by using the l'hospital rule.

Then, there are no horizontal / oblique asymptotes since both limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$$

are indeterminate.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to somehow show that
   $$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2+2k\pi)^{+}}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1} = +\infty$$ in a different way? I mean, without using the l'hospital rule? The same with $$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2+2k\pi)^{-}}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1} = -\infty$$
2. I am not sure how to prove that the limits $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$ are indeterminate.

For now, I took two sequences: $x_n'=\frac{pi}{4} + 2n\pi$ and $x_n'= n\pi$. For both of them, we have infinity as n goes to infinity. Since $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(x_n')=-\sqrt(2)-2$ and $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(x_n'')=0$, the limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ is indeterminte. Similarly with $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$, by taking: $x_n'=\frac{pi}{4} - 2n\pi$ and $x_n'= -n\pi$.

Is it correct?

3. Is the facts $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)-1}$ are indeterminate enough to conclude that there are no oblique asymptotes? Or should I show that also $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ are indeterminate? If yes, could you give my any hints?

I would be very grateful for any hints or help.

Comment: Oblique asymptotes are usually applicable to rational functions. I do not think you need to worry about them here.

Answer (score 0):

You conclusions seem right to me. Regarding calculating the limits without  l'Hospital rule:$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2^{+}}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x-1}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2^{+}}\frac{\sin 2x \cdot (\sin x +1)}{(\sin x-1)(\sin x +1)}=-\lim_{x\to\pi/2^{+}}\frac{2\sin x\cdot (\sin x +1)}{\cos x}=+\infty$$

Comment: Shouldn't we have there $cos^2(x)$?

Comment: @gaghan: $\sin 2x=2 \sin x \cos x$ so one cosine will cancel out

Comment: Sure, thanks. I do not get one more thing... So in the numerator, we have 2*1*(1+1)=4 and in the denomiantor cos(x) is negative for x approaching pi/2 from the right side, so we have [4/0-], so it is minus infity.

Comment: We should have -cos(x) in the denominator, right?

Comment: @gaghan: I put that minus upfront instead of $- \cos x$ in the denominator

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot!